# Program language gaming

Tags: gaming

I would like to know currently and in the near future, if you were going to enter the gaming development world what programming language would you concentrate on?  Also at work level, what is the most requested programming language in this field?

My knowledge is limited to HTML and C. I was thinking about C++ but someone says it's getting obsolete in the near future, so I'm not sure now.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please note that asking for programming languages is off-topic here. For details, see: [Should programming language recommendations be allowed here?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/185)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use game dev engines like unity and unreal that they are awesome! most of games you play on internet are made by these stuff. if you are a beginner I recommend you using unity engine to create 2d or 3d games.

Unity uses c# and Unreal uses C++! as my point of view there is no much difference in language you use. you should choose a great game engine and stick to it to be pro!